# External HDD not recognized by tablet

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb, storage

I have an external 320GB HDD with Backtrack on it, partitioned as follows:
-partition '/' ext4
-partition '/home' ext4
-swap
-free partition fat32

The problem comes when I connect it to my tablet [Vonino Orin S --jellybean 4.1.1]; even if I connect the HDD to an external power supply the tablet doesn't recognize it; even more, sometimes I get a notification "Storage removed. Insert a new one.".

Is there a specific way [size, FS] my HDD must to be partitioned?

Comment: It may be looking for FAT, unfortunately.